# java.time ISO date format with fixed millis digits (in Java 8 and later)

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

By default, the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method of [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) uses the [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter. That formatter won’t print the digits for fraction-of-second if they happen to be 0.

[java-time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) examples:

```
    2015-10-08T17:13:07.589Z
    2015-10-08T17:13:07Z
```

[Joda-Time](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.joda.org%2Fjoda-time%2F) examples (and what I'd expect from java.time):

```
    2015-10-08T17:13:07.589Z
    2015-10-08T17:13:07.000Z
```

This is really frustrating to parse in some systems. [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) was the first problem I encountered, there's no pre-defined format that supports optional millis, but I can probably work around that with a custom format. The default just seems wrong.

It appears that you can’t really build your own format string for Instants anyway. Is the only option implementing my own java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.InstantPrinterParser?

Comment: Your goal is to just find if the date has millisecond precision?

Comment: Goal is to format that date with the fractional second part even if those milliseconds are equal to 0. In other words, mimic what Joda does.

Comment: Quick Reminder: java.time provides a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), as opposed to the milliseconds resolution of Joda-Time & java.util.Date. That is means up to nine (9) digits of a fractional second. So if you limit to 3, you may be hiding/losing data. See [this diagram of mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OW0RW.png).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just create a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) that keeps three fractional digits.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant(3).toFormatter();
```

Then use it. For example:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)));
```

…prints (at the time I run it):

```
2015-10-08T21:26:16.571Z
2015-10-08T21:26:16.000Z
```

Excerpt of the [class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendInstant--):

> … The fractionalDigits parameter allows the output of the fractional second to be controlled. Specifying zero will cause no fractional digits to be output. From 1 to 9 will output an increasing number of digits, using zero right-padding if necessary. The special value -1 is used to output as many digits as necessary to avoid any trailing zeroes. …