# Force Milliseconds When Serializing Instant to ISO8601 using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson2

I have some questions related to **JSON serialization using Jackson** in a project where I use `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6`, `Spring Framework 5.0.1.RELEASE` and `Jackson 2.9.2`.

I have configured the following Jackson-related settings in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

Serialization works mostly as I need. Nevertheless, I have noticed that Jackson seems to cut-off milliseconds if they are `000`.

**Test 1: Serialize Instant with milliseconds set to `000`:**

- Initialize Instant field using `Instant.parse("2017-09-14T04:28:48.000Z")`
- Serialize it using Jackson
- Output will be `"2017-09-14T04:28:48Z"`

**Test 2: Serialize Instant with milliseconds set to some non-`000` value:**

- Initialize Instant field using `Instant.parse("2017-09-14T04:28:48.100Z")`
- Serialize it using Jackson
- Output will be `"2017-09-14T04:28:48.100Z"`

**Questions**:

- Is that behavior by design?
- Is there anything I can do to force serialization of `000`?

Comment: Seems similar to this github issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/issues/39

Comment: @SeanCarroll Yes indeed. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 12):

I solve using this aproach:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
module.addSerializer(Instant.class, new InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

And for InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision i used this:

```
public class InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision extends InstantSerializer {

    public InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision() {
        super(InstantSerializer.INSTANCE, false, new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant(3).toFormatter());
    }
}
```

Now the Instant serialization always includes milliseconds. Example: **2019-09-27T02:59:59.000Z**

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be a Jackson issue open for this [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/issues/39)*. That link contains two workarounds

**Workaround 1**

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ").format(zonedDateTime));
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

**Workaround 2**

```
JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class,
  new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(javaTimeModule);
```

---

<sup>*Link is dead because they deprecated FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310 and moved it to [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/76</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, my Instants still have no `.000` when serialized. Tried your first workaround. I created a configuration class and added an ObjectMapper bean using **Primary** annotation to override the auto-configured object mapper.

Comment: I tried Jackson 2.9.5. and this issue is still not fixed. But your 1.st workaround works, thank you

Comment: I was looking here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed for the issue .. maybe this is the one? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/70

Comment: Workaround 1 works for me. And you should take care of the order of the registered modules.

Comment: The issue further goes to seconds if milliseconds and seconds both are 000 and 00 respectively. If I use 2020-02-04T08:26.00.000Z my output is 2020-02-04T08:26Z. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this in Spring Boot and want to use @Gustavo's answer.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Module javaTimeModule() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addSerializer(new InstantSerializerWithMilliSecondPrecision());
        return module;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of two workarounds mentioned by Sean Carroll works me. I end up with writing my own serializer for Instant.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(Instant.class, new KeepMillisecondInstantSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);

public class KeepMillisecondInstantSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Instant instant, final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        final String serializedInstant = dateTimeFormatter.format(instant);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(serializedInstant);
    }
}
```

I guess Jackson [use `Instant.toString()` method to serialize Instant objects](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/master/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/InstantSerializerBase.java#L101) by default. I also find [some discussions about `Instant.toString()` method on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025988/java-time-iso-date-format-with-fixed-millis-digits-in-java-8-and-later).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fixing the bug of Jackson library, following could be a quick work around:
Create a string variable in the POJO class where you have Timestamp variable:

```
private Timestamp createTimeStamp;

private String stringCreateTimeStamp;
```

capture timestamp value as a string:

```
listOfPojo.forEach(pojo-> {
            pojo.setStringCreateTimeStamp(request.getcreateTimeStamp().toString());
        });
```

Refer https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-timestamp for conversions

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by using custom serializers for **LocalDateTime** and **ZonedDateTime** classes.

**My solution works for me because I use only these two classes in API responses to represent date and time! I don't use Instant or Date so pay attention on it.**

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {

@Bean
fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule().apply {
        addSerializer(LocalDateTime::class.java, KeepMillisecondLocalDateTimeSerializer())
        addSerializer(ZonedDateTime::class.java, KeepMillisecondZonedDateTimeSerializer())
    }
    mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule)
    return mapper
}

class KeepMillisecondZonedDateTimeSerializer : JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun serialize(
        value: ZonedDateTime,
        jsonGenerator: JsonGenerator,
        serializerProvider: SerializerProvider?
    ) {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(value))
    }
}

class KeepMillisecondLocalDateTimeSerializer : JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime>() {
    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun serialize(
        value: LocalDateTime,
        jsonGenerator: JsonGenerator,
        serializerProvider: SerializerProvider?
    ) {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(value))
    }
}
}
```