# Database DateTime milli and nano seconds are truncated by default if they are 0s, while using it in Java 11 using ZonedDateTime

Tags: datetime, java-8, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

I am fetching datetime from an Oracle database and parsing in [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11) using ZonedDateTime as below:

1. Oracle --> `1/19/2020 06:09:46.038631 PM`

   Java *[ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)* output --> `2020-01-19T18:09:46.038631Z[UTC]`
2. Oracle --> `1/19/2011 4:00:00.000000 AM`

   Java *ZonedDateTime* output --> `2011-01-19T04:00Z[UTC]` (So, here the 0s are truncated by default.
   However, my requirement is to have consistent fixed length output like #1.)

**Expected Java ZonedDateTime output --> `2011-01-19T04:00:00.000000Z[UTC]`**

However, I didn’t find any date API methods to achieve above expected output. Instead of manipulating a string, is there a way to preserve the trailing 0s with fixed length?

We have consistent ZonedDateTime types in the application, so we do not prefer to change that.

Comment: How do you print it? With `System.out::println`? You should use a formatter to output the formatted output of your `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I want to write it to file with desired format

Comment: @deval.techie - Write the value of `String output`, as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63936229/10819573), into the file.

Comment: Just use [`ZonedDateTime.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) with a `DateTimeFormatter` specifying your desired number of decimals.

Comment: Two possibly related questions, [OffsetDateTime is not showing milisecond if the string contains 000 \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890384/offsetdatetime-is-not-showing-milisecond-if-the-string-contains-000) and [String to ZonedDateTime is changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have consistent ZonedDateTime type in application, so we do not
> prefer to change that.

Why do you think `2011-01-19T04:00Z[UTC]` is inconsistent? A date-time object is supposed to hold (and provide methods/functions to operate with) only the date, time, and time-zone information. It is not supposed to store any formatting information; otherwise, it will violate the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). The formatting should be handled by a formating class e.g. DateTimeFormatter ([for modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)), `DateFormat` (for legacy `java.util` date-time API) etc.

Every class is supposed to override the `toString()` function; otherwise, `Object#toString` will be returned when its object will be printed. A `ZonedDateTime` has date, time and time-zone information. Given below is how its `toString()` for time-part has been implemented:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(18);
    int hourValue = hour;
    int minuteValue = minute;
    int secondValue = second;
    int nanoValue = nano;
    buf.append(hourValue < 10 ? "0" : "").append(hourValue)
        .append(minuteValue < 10 ? ":0" : ":").append(minuteValue);
    if (secondValue > 0 || nanoValue > 0) {
        buf.append(secondValue < 10 ? ":0" : ":").append(secondValue);
        if (nanoValue > 0) {
            buf.append('.');
            if (nanoValue % 1000_000 == 0) {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue / 1000_000) + 1000).substring(1));
            } else if (nanoValue % 1000 == 0) {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue / 1000) + 1000_000).substring(1));
            } else {
                buf.append(Integer.toString((nanoValue) + 1000_000_000).substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

As you can see, the second and nano parts are included in the returned string only when they are greater than `0`. It means that you need to use a formatting class if you want these (second and nano) zeros in the output string. Given below is an example:

```
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.ZoneOffset;
    import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String input = "1/19/2011 4:00:00.000000 AM";

            // Formatter for input string
            DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                                .appendPattern("M/d/u H:m:s.n a")
                                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

            ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, inputFormatter).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

            // Print `zdt` in default format i.e. the string returned by `zdt.toString()`
            System.out.println(zdt);

            // Formatter for input string
            DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnz");
            String output = zdt.format(outputFormatter);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
2011-01-19T04:00Z
2011-01-19T04:00:00.000000Z
```

### Food for thought:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 5.0000;
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

What output do you expect from the code given above? Does `5.0` represent a value different from `5.0000`? How will you print `5.0000`? [Hint: Check `String#format`, `NumberFormat`, `BigDecimal` etc.]

Comment: thanks a lot Arvind. I wasnt aware abt the exact pattern. it works correctly.

Comment: Actually, "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnz" was causing length issue..e,g, for 0's it was givng perfect 6 digits for nanos in o/p but for nonzeros with 6 digit at source date, its giving 9 digits output for nanos by adding 3 0s. So, i have little modiefied the patterns which gives consistent result for my expected output : "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z['z']'" . The generated string o/p : "2020-04-14T15:51:58.109932Z[UTC]"

Answer (score 0):

Small thing to add to other answers: The fraction-of-second (`S`) and nanos (`n`) are similar but nanos will output more places/digits if more are available. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) didn't seem to elaborate this well. If only up to 6 nano digits are available, then there shouldn't be a difference.

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.format.*;
 
public class TestFormats {
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
        System.out.println("Current time: "
                           + formatter.format(dt));

        System.out.println("New LocalDateTime with 0 nano: "
                           + formatter.format(dt.withNano(0)));
        System.out.println("New LocalDateTime with specific nano: "
                           + formatter.format(dt.withNano(80888)));
        System.out.println("New LocalDateTime with specific bigger nano: "
                           + formatter.format(dt.withNano(8088888)));
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn'Z'");
        System.out.println("Format2 Current time: "
                           + formatter2.format(dt));

        System.out.println("Format2 New LocalDateTime with 0 nano: "
                           + formatter2.format(dt.withNano(0)));
        System.out.println("Format2 New LocalDateTime with specific nano: "
                           + formatter2.format(dt.withNano(80888)));
        System.out.println("Format2 New LocalDateTime with specific bigger nano: "
                           + formatter2.format(dt.withNano(8088888)));
                           
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Current time: 2023-07-12 15:55:30.321719Z
New LocalDateTime with 0 nano: 2023-07-12 15:55:30.000000Z
New LocalDateTime with specific nano: 2023-07-12 15:55:30.000080Z
New LocalDateTime with specific bigger nano: 2023-07-12 15:55:30.008088Z
Format2 Current time: 2023-07-12T15:55:30.321719992Z
Format2 New LocalDateTime with 0 nano: 2023-07-12T15:55:30.000000Z
Format2 New LocalDateTime with specific nano: 2023-07-12T15:55:30.080888Z
Format2 New LocalDateTime with specific bigger nano: 2023-07-12T15:55:30.8088888Z
```