# simpledate formater to format returns incorrect.deducted date after formating

Tags: java, date

I am attempting to parse date using SimpleDateFormat. The date is parsed successfully but the output date format is incorrect or deducted by a year, The Date method that uses SimpleDateFormat is shown below

```
public Date parseDate(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD",Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date parsedDate = null;
        try {
            parsedDate = format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parsedDate;
    }
```

Here is the sample image parsed

```
Date start = parseDate(dateVal); // dateVal sample is 2020-09-25
```

When the date is parsed, this is the output

```
Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 WAT 2019
```

My challenge is to return a date sample of - 2020-09-25 after parsing

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I didn’t understand the downvote. Would someone please explain? The question has desired result, short and complete code example and how observed output differs. It may not report any search, but while this answer has been asked and answered before, those original questions are not easy to find in a search when you don’t know what the root of the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the wrong symbols. Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`. Note that `DD` stands for the **Day of the year** and `Y` stands for **Week year**. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about it.

Also, I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are using Android and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java8, check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2020-09-25");
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-25
```

Note that since your date-time string is already in the ISO8601 format, you do not need to use any `DateTimeFormatter` while parsing it to `LocalDate` as it is the default pattern used by [`LocalDate#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Using the legacy date-time API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse("2020-09-25");
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-09-25] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]

Comment: @Blaze - Just run my code without any change. It's already tested code. If you want to put my code into your method, just put `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  return sdf.parse(date);` into your method and it will work without any issue.

Comment: the output is incorrect after consoling - Fri Sep 25 00:00:00 WAT 2020  expecting - 2020-09-25 15:57:00.217, test from your end to confirm

Comment: @Blaze What makes you expect 15:57:00.217? Where should those come from? Do you want to mention this in the question?

Comment: sorry, my input is of that format from testing with different params, it has date and time, meanwhile I have accepted this as a valid answer

Comment: @Blaze - Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63870230/10819573 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63936229/10819573 and let me know if you still need any further help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
parsedDate = format.parse(date);
```

You should be using `parse(String)` instead of `parseDate()`

Comment: You need one more correction to your pattern: `DD` needs to be replaced with `dd`.